# Exclude index 0 of an array as an option for output?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I'm in my first semester and need complete a restaurant order project. 
Everything is going well but I'm hung up on this one project stipulation:

iii. Once the current diner’s selections have been made display a list of all the items they selected. Don’t display the item if they chose the first option on each menu: No selection.

no selection is index 0 of the array. how can I exclude just index 0?

this is one of the 4 do while loops where the user enters their selection and the data is validated, if it helps, I'm totally stuck. Thanks!

```
System.out.println("Please select one item from the beverages menu.");
do {
    for(int j = 0; j < beveragesArray.length; j++) {
        System.out.println((j + 1) + ". " + 
                           beveragesArray[j] + " $" + beveragesPriceArray[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter your selection #: ");
    beverageSelection = input.nextInt();

    if(beverageSelection < 1 || beverageSelection > beveragesArray.length) {
        System.out.println("We don't serve that, what else would you like?");
        badDataFlag = true;
    } else {
        badDataFlag = false;
        accumulator += beveragesPriceArray[beverageSelection - 1];
        break;
    }               
} while (badDataFlag = true);
```

Here's what the output is supposed to look like for the project.

```
Please select one item from the Appetizer menu.

1. **No selection** $0.00
2. Deep Fried Calamari $7.50
3. Soup du Jour $4.99
4. Garden Salad $3.99
5. Garlic Bread $4.50

Please enter your selection #: 6
INVALID SELECTION. Please enter your selection #: 1

Please select one item from the Entrée menu.

1. **No selection** $0.00
2. Rib-Steak $15.95
3. Fettuccini Alfredo $11.25
4. Pan-Fried Sole $17.95
5. Mediterranean Platter $13.50
6. Vegetarian Lasagna $9.00

Please enter your selection #: 4

Please select one item from the Dessert menu.

1. **No selection** $0.00
2. Ice Cream Sundae $2.95
3. Cheesecake $5.00
4. Chocolate Truffle Cake $6.00
5. Raspberry Mousse $4.50

Please enter your selection #: 5

Please select one item from the Beverage menu.

1. **No selection** $0.00
2. Water $0.00
3: Juice
4. Pop $2.00
5. Milk $2.00
6. Coffee $1.75
7. Tea $1.75

Please enter your selection #: 6

Thank you, Evelyn. Your order consists of:

Pan-Fried Sole
Raspberry Mousse
Tea
```

Comment: instead of tea, for beverage, i think it must be coffee...

Comment: Loop through all their selection (you could save what they selected in an array), if the selectedArray[index]=0, don't print out the selection.

Comment: It would help if you show us the part of the code that you print the final order to the user. There are several ways to do what you want to do. Have you tried creating an array to store the items that the user had selected? Then, in the end of the user selection, you could just print the array with a for loop, but testing if the next array item is "No Selection". If it is, you could just skip this item.

Comment: This is a mistake by the way `do {...} while (badDataFlag = true);`. It is an infinite loop. You mean `do {...} while(badDataFlag);`.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. R SChultz, you were right but my prof is a stickler for "bloat code" so I'm going to go with Yazan's method. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to solve this, the easiest is is to add "Item 1 No Selection" as you currently do then when printing the output, just use an if statement.  If the value is Item 1, than do not print anything, otherwise, print what it was.

While your corresponding code isn't posted, it could be something as simple as this.

```
if ( itemSelectedindex > 0 ){
     // print something tasty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declarea String , to accumulate the order, NOT adding the items with index =0
declare this string out of all do-while loops, maybe first line in main()

```
String customerOrder = "";
```

and at this location, add the new if statement

```
if(beverageSelection < 1 || beverageSelection > beveragesArray.length) {
    System.out.println("We don't serve that, what else would you like?");
    badDataFlag = true;
} else {
    badDataFlag = false;
    accumulator += beveragesPriceArray[beverageSelection - 1];

    //NEW CODE//
    if(beverageSelection != 1){//1. **No selection** $0.00
        customerOrder += beveragesArray[beverageSelection - 1] + "\n";
    }
    //NEW CODE//

    break;
}
```

and at the end, after all items were picked,

```
System.out.println("Thank you, Evelyn. Your order consists of:");
System.out.println(customerOrder );
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I was getting worried about mark deductions for bloat code doing it with ifs for each sub-menu, this is super elegant. Much appreciated.

Comment: good to hear that, so if this works as you need, plz mark this as Answer